# Spring Cloud Gateway: How to modify SSE Flux Stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Having service A with a method that responds with SSE Event stream.
2. Having a gateway that covers the actual service.
3. The objective is to forward request, then intercept, modify **each event** and forward modified response back to client

I implemented folowing `AbstractGatewayFilterFactory` that suposed to modify any response body by attaching a simple string, but failed.

```
@Component
public class TaskQueueFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<TaskQueueFilter.Config> {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaskQueueFilter.class);


    public TaskQueueFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = response.bufferFactory();

            ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(response) {

                @Override
                public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                    if (body instanceof Flux) {
                        Flux<? extends DataBuffer> flux = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;

                        return super.writeWith(flux.buffer().map(dataBuffers -> {
                            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            dataBuffers.forEach(i -> {
                                byte[] array = new byte[i.readableByteCount()];
                                i.read(array);
                                try {
                                    outputStream.write(array);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });
                            try {
                                outputStream.write("0123456789abcdefg".getBytes());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return dataBufferFactory.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray());
                        }));
                    }
                    return super.writeWith(body);
                }
            };

            ServerWebExchange swe = exchange.mutate().response(decoratedResponse).build();
            return chain.filter(swe);
        };
    }


    public static class Config {

    }
}
```

I have tried `ModifyResponseBody`, but it was not working as well.
Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: "failed" and "not working" meaning? I've never tried so I don't know if its possible.

Comment: @spencergibb, in first case, during debugging, method `writeWith` was never triggered, while in case of `ModifyResponseBody` Mono was working okay, but it is not working with Flux, since there is a comment about it in the source. So I wanted to modify it myself, but no luck so far :(